# Fedora - Integrated microphone not working

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa

I just installed a fresh Fedora 21, my system is now up to date.

Now, my problem is that my integrated microphone is not working.

I tried several different fixes that doesn't work (install and manage sound with pulseaudio, change settings in alsamixer, ...).

I don't know what to do now :/

I have got a Dell XPS 15 Laptop with Fedora 21.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you using Fedora Workstation? Just to be sure, did you try the "Sound" config panel (in the Input tab) before you tried more complicated measures?

Comment: Yes, I user Fedora Worksation. And I checked the input tab in the Sound panel

Comment: Did the microphone show up there at all?

Comment: Yep, I see it in the panel

Comment: Did you get any answer? I have the same problem with my HP Elitebook 2570p